# How to keep image lumpted with last word in a paragraph

Tags: jquery, css

I have a sentence that ends with an image:

```
<p>This is a long word This is a long word This long<img src="images/fancy-r.png"></p>
```

When the sentence gets too long, the image ends up on a new line by itself like the picture below. The sentence is dynamically generated, so I can't predict its length. Is there a way to always keep the image "lumped" with the *last word* using CSS or JQ (so that it's never by itself)?
I know how to solve this using background image, but I want to avoid that. Need IE9+ support.

**Edited:** I need to be able to wrap the paragraph.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to insert markup into the sentence?

Comment: I can insert markup at the end of the sentence only. So I could add something around the <img> if I need to...

Comment: Are you ok with jQuery changing the contents of the `<p>` dynamically after it loads?

Comment: ^I think that would be fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial CSS-only solution didn't work in IE so here's an updated one, also CSS-only. Tested in IE9, 10 and 11, Firefox 31 and 32, Chrome 32 and 36.

You need to wrap your image in a `<span>` with `white-space:nowrap` and some additional properties.

**HTML:**

```
<p>
    This is a long word This is a long word This long<span class="stay-together"><img src="images/fancy-r.png"></span>
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.stay-together {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

span:before {
    /* 
     * Chrome requires some content (empty is OK).
     * IE9 needs at least a space character.
    */
    content: " ";
    /* IE9 needs font-size to be greater than 0: */
    font-size: 1px;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/42vp7r8d/).

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can do this with CSS-Only (I am aware of) is to wrap the text and image in it's own span:

```
<p>This is a long word This is a long word This 
  <span class="nowrap">long <img src="images/fancy-r.png"></span>
</p>
```

Then apply CSS to it:

```
.nowrap
{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5pbk9djp/)